# Jersey Path Regex Causing Method Not Allowed for PUT

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm testing out Jersey and I can't seem to figure out why I get a `405 Method Not Allowed` when I call `PUT`:

```java
@Singleton @Path("images")
public class ImageResource {
    private static final String IMAGE_ID_PATH_PARAM = "{imageId : [A-Za-z0-9_\\-]+}";
    private static final String EXTENSION_PATH_PARAM = "{extension : (\\.[A-Za-z]+)?}";

    @GET @Path(IMAGE_ID_PATH_PARAM + EXTENSION_PATH_PARAM)
    @Produces("image/*")
    public Response getImage(@PathParam("imageId") String imageId,
        @PathParam("extension") String extension, @QueryParam("mods") String mods) {
        ...
    }

    @PUT @Path(IMAGE_ID_PATH_PARAM)
    @Consumes("image/*")
    public Response putImage(@PathParam("imageId") String imageId, File image) {
        ...
    }
}
```

`PUT` only works if I set the `@GET` path to `@Path(IMAGE_ID_PATH_PARAM)`. When I add the extension part, I am getting a `405` status code. `GET` seems to work in both cases. Here's the output from a failed `PUT`:

```
$ curl -v --header "Content-Type: image/jpeg" --upload-file /Users/andy/Desktop/test.jpg http://localhost:9090/images/abcde
* About to connect() to localhost port 9090 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9090 (#0)
> PUT /images/abcde HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: localhost:9090
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
> Content-Length: 48198
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Date: Mon, 20 Aug 2012 18:35:59 GMT
< Allow: GET,OPTIONS,HEAD
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I've also tried testing without the `@Produces` and `@Consumes` annotations and it did not work either.

Comment: Have you tried adding `EXTENSION_PATH_PARAM` to `putImage`? You can just not use it.

Comment: Hmm...I just tried it and it works! Can you explain why this works? Very perplexing! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I think I know the reason but I'll have to check it myself to be sure. I'll get back and post an answer when I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at what happens when you send the request.

### Situation 1: no extension

Your methods look like this:

```
    @GET @Path(IMAGE_ID_PATH_PARAM)
    @Produces("image/*")
    public Response getImage(@PathParam("imageId") String imageId,
        @PathParam("extension") String extension, @QueryParam("mods") String mods) {
        ...
    }

    @PUT @Path(IMAGE_ID_PATH_PARAM)
    @Consumes("image/*")
    public Response putImage(@PathParam("imageId") String imageId, File image) {
        ...
    }
```

When you send the following request:

`PUT http://localhost:9090/images/abcde`

first of all, Jersey looks for resources with the URI in question:
`http://localhost:9090/images/abcde`

After the resource is found, it checks what methods can be used to access it.
In this case, you have a single resource with the path defined by `IMAGE_ID_PATH_PARAM`. This resource can be accessed by either `GET` or `PUT` requests. Just like you specified with the annotations.

### Situation 2: extension added to `getImage`

You methods now look like this:

```
@GET @Path(IMAGE_ID_PATH_PARAM + EXTENSION_PATH_PARAM)
@Produces("image/*")
public Response getImage(@PathParam("imageId") String imageId,
    @PathParam("extension") String extension, @QueryParam("mods") String mods) {
    ...
}

@PUT @Path(IMAGE_ID_PATH_PARAM)
@Consumes("image/*")
public Response putImage(@PathParam("imageId") String imageId, File image) {
    ...
}
```

Again, you send the same request:
`PUT http://localhost:9090/images/abcde`

And yet again, Jersey finds the first resource matching the URL. The resource is represented by your `getImage` method, just like the first time. This time again, the `@GET` annotation does not match your request. And just like before, Jersey tries to find another method available for the resource, in order to match your request.

This time, however, no such method is found so it returns a 405.

The reason why this happens is that the methods `getImage` and `putImage` now represent different resources. If you look carefully, the paths can be read like this (I'll omit the regex for clarity):

`@Path({imageId}{extension})` for `getImage`

and

`@Path({imageId})` for `putImage`

While these two paths, considering the regex, can become the same thing, Jersey still sees them as identifiers of separate resources.

If you take a look at the WADL (feel free to look [here](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/) if you're not familiar with the standard) file generated by Jersey (it should be available at `http://localhost:9090/application.wadl`), you'll notice that this is exactly what's happening.

```
<application xmlns="http://research.sun.com/wadl/2006/10">
<resources base="http://localhost:9090/">
<resource path="images">
  <resource path="{imageId : [A-Za-z0-9_\-]+}">
    <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="imageId" style="template" type="xs:string"/>
    <method id="putImage" name="PUT">
      <request>
        <representation mediaType="image/*"/>
      </request>
      <response>
        <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
      </response>
    </method>
  </resource>
  <resource path="{imageId : [A-Za-z0-9_\-]+}{extension : (\.[A-Za-z]+)?}">
    <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="extension" style="template" type="xs:string"/>
    <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="imageId" style="template" type="xs:string"/>
    <method id="getImage" name="GET">
      <request>
        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="mods" style="query" type="xs:string"/>
      </request>
      <response>
        <representation mediaType="image/*"/>
      </response>
    </method>
  </resource>
</resource>
</resources>
</application>
```

Notice how `images` has two, separate sub-resources, each one with a single method.

### Solution

Adding the `EXTENSION_PATH_PARAM` segment to `putImage`'s `@Path` annotation causes these two methods to be mapped to a single resource again, so the problem disappears. Since the regex makes this part optional, you are free to omit it and pretend it doesn't exist.

The difference can be clearly seen in the generated WADL.

```
<application xmlns="http://research.sun.com/wadl/2006/10">
  <resources base="http://localhost:9090/">
    <resource path="images">
      <resource path="{imageId : [A-Za-z0-9_\-]+}{extension : (\.[A-Za-z]+)?}">
        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="extension" style="template" type="xs:string"/>
        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="imageId" style="template" type="xs:string"/>
        <method id="putImage" name="PUT">
          <request>
            <representation mediaType="image/*"/>
          </request>
          <response>
            <representation mediaType="*/*"/>
          </response>
        </method>
        <method id="getImage" name="GET">
         <request>
           <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="mods" style="query" type="xs:string"/>
         </request>
         <response>
           <representation mediaType="image/*"/>
         </response>
        </method>
      </resource>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</application>
```

In this case, `images` has exactly one sub-resource, which in turn has two available methods.

Personally, I find the automatic generation of WADL a fantastic feature of Jersey. It's a great way to see what's happening with your resource methods without spending too much time with curl or other REST client.

Comment: Coming from a Spring MVC background, this behavior in Jersey feels a little constraining. It seems that a PUT without a corresponding GET is not possible. However, WADL generation may not be possible without these rules in place, nor could the interface be guaranteed to be REST-ful. Anyway, thanks for the detailed explanation Tom!

Comment: @andy a PUT without a corresponding GET is perfectly valid and possible. Just watch out for the paths. In this case, there was room for ambiguity. As long as you keep the paths either the same, or completely different (not possible to confuse in certain cases), everything will be okay. I'm not very familiar with Spring but learning it is one of the top things on my to-do list.